# syntax on strtoupper using a $_GET variable

Tags: php

How would i use the strtoupper function on this line with a get variable? i need to return the token as an uppercase.

```
else if(isset($_GET['token'])) {        

    $shopper = new Shopper($_GET['token'])
    or die('Could not instantiate a new Shopper from the \'token\' passed-in');

    $array = array();
    $shopper_lists = $shopper->get_lists(true);
    foreach ($shopper_lists as $list) {
         $array[] = $list->json();
    }

      echo json_encode($array);
```

would i insert it after the isset or before or some other method completely??

after it's returning through a json encode it's all lowercase when all the other fields are upper.

Sorry if it's a bit of a noob question... I'm just trying to figure out exactly how to use the strtoupper function in this bit of code.

Comment: `$shopper = new Shopper(strtoupper($_GET['token']))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
$shopper = new Shopper(strtoupper($_GET['token']))
```

Answer (score 2):

Put it right before it goes in:

```
$shopper = new Shopper( strtoupper($_GET['token']) )
```